# CSS property to make text wrappable at any place

Tags: css, whitespace, word-wrap, line-breaks

**Is there a CSS property that tells the browser to word-wrap at any position, not only at word boundaries?**

My current issue is this. I am faced with HTML similar to this: (I cannot change the HTML, unfortunately)

```
<div id='categories'>Categories:
    <ul>
        <li>Category One</li>
        <li>Category Two</li>
        <li>Category Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want it to display in a flowing manner according to the width of the viewport:

```
Categories:  • Category One  • Category Two   • Category Three
|----------------------------------------------------------------| (viewport)

Categories:  • Category One  • Category Two
• Category Three
|----------------------------------------------| (viewport width)

Categories:  • Category One
• Category Two   • Category Three
|----------------------------------| (viewport width)
```

... but **NOT** word-breaking within a category name.

So I tried this:

```
 #categories ul {
  display: inline;
 }
 #categories li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
 #categories li:before {
  content: '• ';
 }
```

Unfortunately this causes them all to run in one line. So I need to be able to tell the `ul` to allow wrapping anywhere between any adjacent `li`s. How do I do that?

**I need a CSS-only solution; I cannot change the HTML...**

Comment: Does the `<ul>` have a parent element?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: Yes, `#categories` :-p

Comment: Hehe, figured that out, added it to my answer :) The demo works, but it doesn't use the break-word as I don't think that fits. It simply sizes the UL element to keep the lis as you wish.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid (both HTML 4 and 5); bare text is not allowed in `<ul>`. I don't offhand know whether all browsers (and/or the HTML5 algorithm) recover the same.

Comment: @KevinReid: You’re right. I checked again and the bare text is actually outside the UL. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful trick for wrapping boxes is to make them all `float: left`. If I do this to your example, then I get the layout you want except for "Categories:" being pushed to the right. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to select the text so as to make it floated.

We can use `content` to re-insert "Categories:" as one of the floated boxes, which leaves the problem of how to hide the existing "Categories:" text without hiding the other contents of `#categories`. The cleanest way I thought of was to make it transparent. However, this is a CSS3 feature; also, this loses any inherited color due to the need to explicitly set it on the `ul`.

This stylesheet produces everything you want, but needs some tweaking for spacing.

```
#categories {
 color: transparent;
}
#categories ul {
 color: black;
}
#categories li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 1em;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
#categories li:before {
 content: '• ';
}
#categories li:first-child:before {
 content: 'Categories: • ';
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the invalid HTML, I copied it down wrong. I edited the question. The bare text is actually outside the UL.

Comment: @Timwi: I've edited my answer; I believe it now answers your question, though it needs some spacing work.

Comment: @KevinReid I recommend `visibility:hidden` and `visibility:visible` over `color:transparent`. The additional advantage is that the text stays invisible when a user selects the text.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know that `visibility` could be counteracted in children.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

`<ul>Categories: <li>Category One</li><wbr><li>Category Two</li><wbr><li>Category Three</li></ul>`

Comment: "(I cannot change the HTML, unfortunately)"